# display ALAssetPropertyDate in UILabel using AssetsLibrary in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm using the following code to get the property date of the video but the problem is it return as `NSDate` and when I tried to assign it to `UILabel.text` in `UITableView` the program crashes. Can anyone help me?

```
 void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *,NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if(result != nil){
                //[Asset addObject:result];

                  if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                    // asset is a video


                    [Asset addObject:result];
                    NSString  *CamDuration = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

                }
            }
        };

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(125, 12, 200, 19);
            UILabel *CamDurationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            CamDurationLabel.tag = 1;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:CamDurationLabel];
            CamDurationLabel.text = CamDuration;

         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy with the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM`, you can use the [`-description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description) method of `NSDate`. In your case, that would be:

```
CamDurationLabel.text = [CamDuration description];
```

If you'd rather a bit more flexibility, look into the [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) class. iOS 4.0+ has a nice class method:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSString *formattedDate = [NSDate localizedStringFromDate:today dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the great tip but how do i display them on a uitable? currently i have 2 video but both the video displayed in uilabel is the same(the latest video date) for each table cell. how do i do this?Thanks in advance